# Unable to connect to my bitbucket repo from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-cloud

I have jenkins installed in EC2 instance. When i try to talk to bitbucket repo:

Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git ls-remote -h

[image: embedded image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing 1 problem on your git configuration, you don't have set any credentials there.
Try to set your user credentials (For bitbucket) on the Jenkins settings.

Answer (score 0):

I tried applying the private key to jenkins credentials page and public key to bitbucket ssh settings page.

We tried a couple of jeknkins bitcucket plugins and and tried applying the following:

1. Add Credentials --> Username and password --> then the bitbucket username and password
2. Add Credentials --> Kind-->SSH Username and private key --> bitbucket username and passphrase as blank
3. Add Credentials-->Kind-->Bitbucket personal access token-->private key-->from the ssh -->username->>bitbucket -->passphrase as blank